# Multiple filters on a data

Tags: django, django-urls

I want have have multiple filters on the data. like first i want to filter by date field and then by type field and then by some other field .... as many times as possible. i must pass on the field and value in the url and it must apply the filter and pass the data to the next filter.

Answer (score 1):

Conditions separated by commas are anded together:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(cond1, cond2)
```

You can use Python's keyword expansion to pass them:

```
condlist = {}
condlist[cond1] = val1
condlist[cond2] = val2
SomeModel.objects.filter(**condlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [django-filter](http://github.com/alex/django-filter).